# Cannot build a ROP chain

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit-development, rop

My ROP exploit crashes with segmentation fault for unknown reason.
This is a vulnerable code (compiled via command `gcc h2.c -no-pie -fno-stack-protector -m32 -o h2`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char string[100];
void exec_string() {
    system(string);
}

void add_bin(int magic) {
    if (magic == 0xdeadbeef) {
        strcat(string, "/bin");
    }
}

void add_sh(int magic1, int magic2) {
    if (magic1 == 0xcafebabe && magic2 == 0x0badf00d) {
        strcat(string, "/sh");
    }
}

void vulnerable_function(char* string) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, string);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string[0] = 0;
    vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I followed this example: https://medium.com/@nikhilh20/return-oriented-programming-rop-chaining-def0677923ad

In addition, there are no suitable gadgets of `pop pop ret` pattern (actually, there are, but `pop [some reg] pop ebp ret`, which messes up the stack as well as gadgets with leave instruction).

I've tried two different stack paddings for an exploit: the first one is identical to the primer in the link I provided above. The second one is (top - higher addresses, bottom - lower addresses):

```
address of exec_string
garbage value
0x0badf00d
0xcafebabe
add esp 8; pop ebx; ret <-- gadget
address of add_sh
0xdeadbeef
pop; ret gadget <-- gadget
address of add_bin <-- compromised instruction pointer after BoF
AAAA
....
112 'A's to overflow the buffer and overwrite ebp (108 + 4)
....
AAAA
```

Let me explain the `add esp, 8; pop ebx; ret` gadget. There are no gadgets like `pop [some reg]; pop [some reg, not ebp]; ret` for chaining calls from add_sh to exec_string functions, so I've tried to make a little hack. I've chosen `add esp, 8; pop ebx; ret` gadget to pop out `0xcafebabe` and `0x0badf00d` via `add esp,8` then pop out garbage unreferenced value via `pop ebx` and then `ret` to exec_string. Does it suppose to work at all? Correct me if I wrong.

Moreover, when I've started debugging, it results with:

[image]

Cool, it looks like I owned an instruction pointer, I need to replace it with add_bin function address to jump to it and start a ROP chain.

But...
[image]

SIGSEGV in 0x91c2b1c2? I've entered a correct add_bin address, ASLR, PIE and canaries are disabled. I thought that maybe there is an undefined reference to string that vulnerable_function gets, but in primer in the link provided above it was ignored, so it confused me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually in Python 3 that couldn't output a raw bytes in a straightforward way like in Python 2.
Also, my theory about `add esp, 8; pop ebx; ret` gadget is correct :) This is an alternative way to build a ROP chain (the garbage value is not referenced by add_sh function, so I can do that without a danger to fall into a segmentation fault, it may come very handy in particular cases when there are few perfect gadgets in the binary).
Here is the exploit:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you fix this issue, I believe you will be successful.

```
gef➤  ropper --search pop
[...]
0x0804901e: pop ebx; ret; 
0x080491c4: pop edi; pop ebp; ret; 
[...]
```

These gadgets don't "mess up" the stack in this case; they clean it up a bit after the overflow so that you are able to return to the next function in the chain. The gadget you picked instead is *close*, but would need to be an `add esp, 4` instead of 8, or without the additional `pop`. You'll see why if you step through it in the debugger.

So, instead use the `pop; pop; ret` from above.

Comment: It fails when I want to jump to add_bin function, look at two debugging screenshots in the question post. How does it happen? I can't jump even to add_bin despite of the fact that I owned the instruction pointer. How does it happen?

Comment: @Asm. The screenshots don't show at what part of execution the segfault occured, are you sure it's at `add_bin`? Maybe you are getting further than you think.